# Issue with starting the first android hello world on netbeans

Tags: android

i download Android 2.2 SDK and install nbandroid plugin on netbeans.
when i run project i get this message on netbeans out put and emulator did not start !!!

> ```
>   init:
>   deps-jar:
>   Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\mahdi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Hello   
>   Android\build\classes
>   compile:
>   =C:\Users\mahdi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Hello was unexpected at this time.
>   C:\Users\mahdi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Hello Android\nbproject\build-impl.xml:411:   
>   exec returned: 255
>  BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
> ```

and this is my code :

```
package org.me.helloandroid;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Hello World");
    setContentView(tv);
}

}
```

can any body help me 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st hint: Avoid spaces in the Project name! This is something you could have seen yourself:

```
\NetBeansProjects\Hello was unexpected
```

A partial file-name in an error message which un-expectantly ends at the first space is a dead give away for a tool which does not support spaces in file names.

That you haven't spotted it yourself leads me to a 2nd advice:

2nd hint: Use Eclipse for Android development.

Comment: does `Hello was unexpected at this time,` in and of itself, tell you that there's a problem with the project name?  or, were you looking at the next line to see that?